# Web api error 500 starting from usermanager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, internal-server-error

First of all, I would like to apologize for my really bad english, if something is not understandable, then reask please.

When I try POST with /api/account/regapi in Swagger then with too short password it gives error 200, but with correct length it gives error 500, while debugging it shows correct parameters at AuthDTO model, but still shows error 500 with correct data.

Response header returned by false data(incorrect password length):

```
 {
  "$id": "1",
  "succeeded": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "code": "PasswordTooShort",
      "description": "Passwords must be at least 6 characters."
    }
  ]
}
```

Response header with incorrect password

```
access-control-allow-origin: * 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Sat, 26 May 2018 13:54:06 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET 
 x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcS29vbGkgQXNqYWRcVlIyXFZSMlByb2pla3RTb2x1dGlvblxWUjJQcm9qZWt0XGFwaVxBY2NvdW50XFJlZ0FwaQ==?=
```

Response header with correct data:

```
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
 date: Sat, 26 May 2018 14:03:59 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET 
 x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcS29vbGkgQXNqYWRcVlIyXFZSMlByb2pla3RTb2x1dGlvblxWUjJQcm9qZWt0XGFwaVxBY2NvdW50XFJlZ0FwaQ==?=
```

Registration in AccountController

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegApi(AuthDTO model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }


public class AuthDTO
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I think the is problem is in _usermanager, because error 500 is starting to show up there

Comment: Put try catch statement around _userManager.CreateAsync and then debug code to see what is the exception